# Problem with having Canvas and Panel rendering on Frame for animation

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, thread-safety

i have problem with canvas Jpanel and  need optimized solution 
i got this design from one of the post on this forum.

i have three classes :

one is for animation which is canvas(BallPanel), one is frame(Main) and one is  panel for swing controls(ControlPanel)

Main is rending both Controlpanel and BallPanel, *but in the end, i can't see the drawworld() rendering from BallPanel but i can only ControlPanel*.

**I can't see animation and black background,seems like controlpanel is all on frame and canvas (black background) is behind/underneath that or somewhere but invisible**

BallPanel:

```
 public BallPanel()
    {
        try {
            this.aBall = (BallServer) Naming
                    .lookup("rmi://localhost/BouncingBalls");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
        box = new Box(0, 0, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);

        // Wire up Events
//      MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();
//      addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);
//      addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
    }



public void drawworld() throws RemoteException {

        if (strategy == null || strategy.contentsLost())
        {
            // Create BufferStrategy for rendering/drawing
            this.createBufferStrategy(2);
            strategy = getBufferStrategy();
            Graphics g = strategy.getDrawGraphics();
            this.g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        }

        // Turn on anti-aliasing
        this.g2.setRenderingHint (RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    //  box.draw(this.g2); // this can be another but it's also not working

        // Render Background
        this.g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        this.g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        serball = aBall.getState();// other version UNcomment this line

        for (int i = 0; i < currentNumBalls; i++) {
            this.g2.setColor(serball[i].getBallColor(velocity.getLength()));
            this.g2
                    .fillOval((int) (serball[i].position.getX() - serball[i]
                            .getRadius()),
                            (int) (serball[i].position.getY() - serball[i]
                                    .getRadius()), (int) (2 * serball[i]
                                    .getRadius()), (int) (2 * serball[i]
                                    .getRadius()));

        }


public void mainLoop() {

        long previousTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long currentTime = previousTime;
        long elapsedTime;
        long totalElapsedTime = 0;
        int frameCount = 0;

        while (true) {
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            elapsedTime = (currentTime - previousTime); // elapsed time in
            // seconds
            totalElapsedTime += elapsedTime;
            if (totalElapsedTime > 1000) {
                currentFrameRate = frameCount;
                frameCount = 0;
                totalElapsedTime = 0;
            }


                try {
                    drawworld();
                } catch (RemoteException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            previousTime = currentTime;
            frameCount++;

        }
    }


public void start()
    {
        mainLoop();
    }
```

the Main class  above start() is calling from here :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {


                JFrame frame = new JFrame("BallBounce");

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


                BallPanel ballCanvas = new BallPanel();

                ControlPanel controlPanel = new ControlPanel(ballCanvas);

                frame.getContentPane().add(ballCanvas);
                frame.getContentPane().add(controlPanel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

                ballCanvas.start();
        }
```

this is controlpanel whichis working as controller:

```
public class ControlPanel extends JPanel {

    private BallPanel mainPanel;
    private JButton resetButton;

    public ControlPanel(BallPanel mainPanel)
    {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 60));
        this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(5000, 100));
        this.mainPanel = mainPanel;

....
..
..
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();

            if (source == resetButton)
            {
                mainPanel.clearBalls();
            }
```

Many thanks for any help and how we could handle such GUI with RMI animation and swing control for interacting/controlling  that
can somebody tell optimized way.
jibby lala

P.S: i thought there is some thread problem while i m calling  the remote method and rendering the drawworld, either of thread is going on suspension or blocked

cross post: http://www.coderanch.com/forums/jforum?module=posts&action=edit&post_id=2406332&start=0

i made this with timer  but the problems persist please help:

```
public CopyOfCleanBallPanel2() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        frame = new JFrame("simple gaming loop in java");
        frame.setSize(BOX_WIDTH, BOX_WIDTH);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        displayCanvas = new CustomCanvas();
        displayCanvas.setLocation(0, 0);
        displayCanvas.setSize(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        displayCanvas.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        displayCanvas.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        displayCanvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH,CANVAS_HEIGHT));

        frame.add(displayCanvas);
        displayCanvas.requestFocus();

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        try {
            this.aBall = (BallServer) Naming
                    .lookup("rmi://localhost/BouncingBalls");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }


        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        aBall.start();
        startFrameTimer();

    }

    /*
     * Initializes the frame (also game update) timer.
     */
    private void startFrameTimer() {
        frameTimer.schedule(new FrameTimerTask(), 1, GAME_TIMER_COOLDOWN);
    }

    public void updateSimulation() throws RemoteException {
        repaintCanvas();
    }
    /*
     * This method gets called by the timer. It updates the game simulation and
     * redraws it.
     */
    private void onFrameTimer() throws RemoteException {
        updateSimulation();
    }

    /*
     * Causes the whole canvas to get repainted.
     */
    private final void repaintCanvas() throws RemoteException  {
        Graphics g =  displayCanvas.getGraphics();
        drawworld(g);
    }

    private class FrameTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            try {
                onFrameTimer();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    /*
     * This custom canvas overrides the paint method thus allowing for a custom
     * painting on the component.
     */
    private class CustomCanvas extends Canvas {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            // Currently the game message gets drawn over the inner border
            // of the canvas so we have to repaint the whole thing.
            try {
                repaintCanvas();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public void drawworld(Graphics g) throws RemoteException {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
             g.fillRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);

            System.out.println("i m in drawworld ");

            serBall = aBall.getState1();// other version UNcomment this line

            System.out.println("i m in drawworld "+serBall.length);

            for (int i = 0; i < currentNumBalls; i++) {
                g.setColor(serBall[i].getBallColor(velocity.getLength()));
                g
                        .fillOval((int) (serBall[i].position.getX() - serBall[i]
                                .getRadius()),
                                (int) (serBall[i].position.getY() - serBall[i]
                                        .getRadius()), (int) (2 * serBall[i]
                                        .getRadius()), (int) (2 * serBall[i]
                                        .getRadius()));

                // Draw our framerate and ball count
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.drawString("FPS: " + currentFrameRate + " Balls: "
                        + currentNumBalls, 15, 15);
            }   
        }
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a thread issue as it appears to me you're calling while (true) and Thread.sleep(...) on the EDT, the main Swing thread.  Have you read up on [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)?  If not, check out the article linked to within.  Also strongly consider using a Swing Timer to drive your animation instead of while (true) and Thread.sleep(...).

Comment: i m looking for some example based on similar design.

Comment: Example of what, a Swing Timer? There are plenty of examples in this forum and in others.  Otherwise your best bet is to try to create this example yourself, and if you get stuck, come on back here, because that's what this forum is for.

Comment: i made that with timer but still problems are there.

Comment: We'll be much better able to help you if you could create an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org).  Please check out the link to see what I mean and why it's important.

Comment: Edit: on quick perusal of your code, I see that you are not using a Swing Timer (javax.swing.Timer) but a java.util.Timer which is not what I recommended and which will not work well. Also you're mixing AWT and Swing code for no good reason which can only cause trouble and suggests that your code needs to be re-thought out.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels:  what do you mean by mixing, if you can give me concrete solution it would be much better, i tried almost every combination but it is not working

Comment: Regarding mixing: you have Swing code including JFrame and JPanels and AWT code including Canvases, and these don't mix well together nor should they be mixed unless you have a good reason for this (you don't) and know what you're doing (you don't and I don't).

Comment: Regarding a concrete solution, I'm a firm believer that the onus of work should be yours.  If you put in the effort to create a decent [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org), many here, myself included will put in the effort to help you get it running as you want it to.